# Intercept numerical subdomain requests

Tags: redirect, htaccess

Is it possible, via .htaccess to intercept all numerical subdomains ex. (02321.example.com), and forward them to example.com/02321

..and HOW do i write it (i'm not god at regex)

and how to get NOT mess upp wordpress while doing it..

and if possible, keep the 02321.example.com adress in the addressfield?

Comment: Yes, you can do this, however, are all these (numerical) subdomains already resolving to your host? By "forward", do you mean "redirect" (or "proxy")?

Comment: @MrWhite yes, all subdomains are resolved to my host, I guess i mean redirect, proxy isn't available thru the .htaccess file (I think)

Comment: What should happen to the URL-path (if any)? eg. What happens to a request for `02321.example.com/foo`? Should `/foo` be preserved (perhaps `example.com/02321/foo`) or simply discarded? Is `/02321` a physical subdirectory? If so, then there should be a trailing slash, ie. `/02321/`. Do these numerical subdomains and the domain apex all point to the same place on the filesystem?

Comment: @MrWhite there is no directories (/foo), only the 02321.example.com, and it would be connected to the post/page on wordpress that has the address example.com/02321, however I've noticed that there isn't any physical directory, and I have no idea how wordpress handles it..